# How to decrypt a GPG file in a PHP script

Tags: php

I'm trying to decrypt a GPG file in a PHP script. I'm trying to decrypt it with GPG tool and I am using the following PHP code:

```
shell_exec('gpg --batch -r '.$passphrase.'  '.$outputFile)
```

... where `$passphrase` is password and `$outputFile` is the file path.

But it's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump( [your shell exec call] );` ?

Comment: define "not working".